# Fetch images from Drupal with c#

Tags: c#, database, image, drupal, fetch

I want to fetch images from a Drupal DB to a C# program.

In Drupal DB the image path is:

> "public://*yourimage.jpg*"

However, this is not a usable URI for C#.

How can I get images from Drupal to C# in a secure way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to fetch the images from a database, the URL is not important, what you need to know is if the image is in the database and in wich tabel, and if images are stores in file system, in which table is the path. Then, use plain Ado.Net to get those images.

If instead you want to fetch images from the web, then you'll need to build some kind of grabber. Maybe CsQuery project can help you in that..
https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery